# Trying to start a directory with java Process, says my file isn't found

Tags: java, file, process, io

I have a gui with WindowBuilder and I want to be able to click a button and then open up a file directory as a new window. I understand that in cmd you use "start" for this, but the following code (where PATH + SideProjs is an absolute filepath starting from C: and "start " is the passed command:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start " + PATH + "SideProjs");
```

Results in this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "start": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:590)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:414)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:311)
    at ProdSystemGUI.openFile(ProdSystemGUI.java:246)
    at ProdSystemGUI$6.actionPerformed(ProdSystemGUI.java:134)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6636)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2764)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:483)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:158)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 41 more
```

Even though the file very much exists. When I do something like:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad " + fileToOpen);
```

It works just fine.

Comment: Perhaps [Desktop.getDesktop().browseFileDirectory](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html#browseFileDirectory(java.io.File))(new File(PATH, "SideProjs")) would be a better choice.

Comment: It is trying to find the "start" file, which doesnt exist. Does this exist in your system?

Comment: "start" is a command implemented by cmd.  So what you want may be a command-line "cmd .....".   But why do you need "start" at all?

Answer (score 0):

The command `start` is built into Windows CMD.EXE so cannot be invoked directly as it is not an executable, so you'd have to invoke CMD.EXE first, such as:

```
String[] cmd = new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "start "+PATH + "SideProjs"};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

There are other ways to open a new File Explorer window as in the comments (if BROWSE_FILE_DIR action is supported) or try:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(PATH+"SideProjs"));
```

or if PATH is a directory:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(PATH, "SideProjs"));
```